# How to pospone javascript event to be triggered if there is another special event registered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work with javascript/jquery to manage action in some buttons, user may not have permission to perform the action of that button, let's say "Update Button", it still click-able but when it's clicked by user who has not permission update, they will be offered to input a 'token' from their supervisor borrow/override their authorization temporarily, then the action of the button work for them.

First I need have normal click event of the button to perform showing dialog update, because in some case they may not have permission I also add click event to show dialog token, I need postpone showing dialog update after they input correct token or it showing dialog update from the first place if they have permission update. I need dynamically do this if they have `data-` configuration, anything registered event do check permission (asking token first), then do another event (whatever event) after that, or cancel if they input wrong token.

```
<button class='btn-update' data-authorized="false" data-permission="update">Update</button> 
<button class='btn-create' data-authorized="false" data-permission="update">Update</button> 

<script>
$('.btn-update').on('click', function(){
    // show update dialog
});

$('.btn-create').on('click', function(){
    // show create dialog
});

$('[data-authorized="false"]').on('click', function(){
    // show token dialog
    // in case for '.btn-update' they call event show dialog update
    // in case for '.btn-create' they call event show dialog create
});
</script>
```

Actually I can do by checking every button that override-able by always check permission attribute, but it's too much. Any suggestion?

Comment: `data-permission` actually what is permission they need, I send to server along with token checking to find out if owner of the token has that permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single event listener on `document.body` that listens on the **capture** phase, and prevent further bubbling when `data-authorized` isn't set.

Doing this prevents jQuery from seeing the event, and thus you can have your code there that always assumes it's authorized. In the below snippet, note that the `create` button works but not `update` due to the `data-authorized` flag.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  if (e.target.getAttribute('data-authorized') === 'false') {
    console.log("NO PERMISSIONS 4 U");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
}, true);

$('.btn-update').on('click', function(){
    alert('update');
});

$('.btn-create').on('click', function(){
    alert('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<button class='btn-update' data-authorized="false" data-permission="update">Update</button> 
<button class='btn-create' data-authorized="true" data-permission="update">Create</button>
```

Comment: It only stop whatever event that registered in buttons, but how to continue propagation after they input correct token?

Comment: You can add your own handling in the global handler to authorize, doing conditional logic based on `e.target`

Comment: Let's say I have 20 buttons, so I need to check which button and which event to be executed? can I just `e.target.run_registered_event()` or at least `e.target.click()` and it run the click event that's stopped by stopPropagation() before?